# Como criar um flexbox com flexitens que são imagens dentro de um hyperlink?

Tags: html5, css3

A ideia é que eu tenha um `flexbox` com duas imagens que são links para outras páginas `html`. Mas quando eu crio o que fica flexível são os `hyperlinks` e não as imagens. O código que estou usando é esse.

```css
body{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: #02010a;
}

.container_img_secundarias{
  background-color: blue;
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.container_img_secundarias img{
  width: 45%;
  flex-basis: 500px;
  margin: 20px 30px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilos.css">
    <title>Minhas fotografias</title>
  </head>

  <body>

    <div class="container_img_secundarias">
      <a href="#"><img id="africa" src="imagens/africa.jpg" alt="África" title="África"></a>
      <a href="#"><img id="coniferas" src="imagens/conifers.jpg" alt="Coníferas" title="Coníferas"></a>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

O que pensei em fazer é isso aqui:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Sendo que as imagens são links e itens do `container flexbox` . Daí elas teriam um `row wrap` para que a segunda imagem vá pra linha debaixo quando necessário.

Comment: O que vc quer dizer com "imagem flexível" como vc quer que a imagem se comporte dentro do link? Te uma imagem do layout final que pretende? Se sim, inclua ela na pergunta

Comment: Coloquei a imagem do que quero fazer.